# Ogr2ogr Clipping data using SQL Server database object for input and overlay

Tags: sql, clip, ogr2ogr, server, cmd

I am trying to understand the ogr2ogr comands for clipping. At this moment I want to clip data using SQL Server database object (dbo)
It did try but no success.

> ogr2ogr.exe -f "GPKG" "C:\Temp\100-polygons-B.gpkg" "MSSQL:server=xx.xxx.xxx.xx,xxx; driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; database=TEST; uid=XXXXXXXXXXX; pwd=XXXXXXXXXX;" -clipsrcsql "SELECT * FROM TEST.dbo.polygons-A WHERE nr='100'" -sql "SELECT * FROM TEST.dbo.polygons-B" -nlt POLYGON -overwrite

So I want to use from dbo.polygons-A polygon number 100 as overlay
For my input i use dbo.polygons-B
At last create I file 100-polygons-B.gpkg

When I run this cmd it gives me no error or warnings. It creates the output file but it does not clip at all.

On my local laptop I tried with shapefiles and that's working.

> ogr2ogr.exe  -clipsrc d:\Temp\A.shp d:\Temp\clipt.gpkg d:\Temp\B.shp -nlt POLYGON -overwrite -clipsrcwhere nr='100'

How can I get this working?

Comment: This probably does not resolve your problem, but consider renaming your tables. If the table name contains dots and a minus sign the standard SQL requires using delimited identifiers. I do not know MSSQL and the exact syntax that is needed but I guess it is something like `SELECT * FROM "TEST"."dbo.polygons-A"`, and the internal double quotes must be escaped, so it would become `SELECT * FROM \"TEST\".\"dbo.polygons-A\"`.